# React component theme using sass variables depending on React prop value

Tags: reactjs, sass, theming

I cannot find better solution for theming. I have a sass-file with variables:

*vars.scss:*

```
$colors: (
    dark: (
        theme1: #0096dc,
        theme2: #eb8200,
        …
    ),
    …
);
```

For now I pass `theme` prop to all components which should have some styling depending on which page user is viewing. In React I build classname like this:

```
<div className={styles[`button${theme ? `-${theme}` : ``}`]}>{children}</div>
```

and in sass I do:

```
@import 'vars';

.button{
    /* basic styles */
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 1px solid;

    @each $theme, $color in map-get($colors, dark) {
        &-#{$theme} {
            @extend .button;
            border-color: $color;
            color: $color;
        }
    }
}
```

But this is absolutely inconvenient, because I need to place such code every time I need to style element depending on theme.

There are solutions how to load different files with variables for theming in webpack, but I receive `theme` prop from redux, so webpack doesn't have access to that prop.

As well as, I cannot find solution to pass property from react component to sass. Only opposite.

No way to use variables in imports in sass. Still not implemented.

Unfortunately, Cannot use CSS-in-JS approach in current project.

Please help to find better approach.

Answer (score 1):

I would make it a stateless functional component.

```
function BrightBox(props){
  <div className={styles[`button${theme ? `-${theme}` : ``}`]}>
    {props.children}
  </div>
}
```

Then import it and use it. There is no need to pass theme around.

```
{user.notice ? 
  <BrightBox>
    there are {user.notice.issues.size} outstanding issues!
  </BrightBox>
 : null
}
```

Comment: The only other suggestion I would make to this would be to look into using [React's Context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) for accessing the `theme` prop, instead of passing it around everywhere.

Comment: And before anyone says anything about Context only being an experimental API: https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/749715530454622208

Comment: How your example will help me to get rid of placing loops in sass each time I need to use themes colors?

Ok, I can use context, whatever. But I want to get rid of that prop at all! I want to write like this:

    `<div className={styles.button}>{children}</div>`

But sass should use $theme-color variable according to theme.

    `.button{
        font-size: 14px;
        border: 1px solid $theme-color;
        color: $theme-color;
    }`

`$theme-color` here should be loaded depending on `theme` prop.