# Server side rendering - switch between css bundles

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a SSR application - (React+express)
and have my webpack like so:

```
entry: {
           main: ['babel-polyfill', './client/index.js'],
           site1css: './components/site1/scss/main.scss',
           site2css: './components/site2/scss/main.scss',
        },
```

I will have 2 separate css bundles in my dist folder - in my server.js file
I am injecting appropriate css bundle based on the route for the first time.

But how do I update to another css file when the route changes from site1 to site2 and vice versa (Ihave a link to site2 on site1 and site1 on site2) I need to have these application together can not split that now - is there a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The webpack entry can be used to switch css bundles only on initial build. For achieving this based on routing, maybe you can define two sets of scss files and render classes based on supplying the theme variable using react theme context provider.

Rendering classes based on theme is a tedious process, but I have been stuck up with the same problem ur facing and could not find any work around.

Also have a look at this tag, if u haven't [React component theme using sass variables depending on React prop value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388393/react-component-theme-using-sass-variables-depending-on-react-prop-value)